# The Hill (from Spoon River anthology) - Exact meaning of a verse

Tags: poetry, mistranslation

I was reading an Italian translation of the following verse from "The Hill":

> They brought them dead sons from the war,
>   And daughters whom life had crushed, ...

The translation is ambiguous on the first line, and on the second line it says something like "and daughters crushed by the (their) life", which sounds erroneous to me. Can someone explain in prose the exact meaning?

Comment: You want the exact meaning of the original or of the mistranslation?

Comment: @KillingTime, I ask for the exact meaning, in order to see whether the translation is bad. Giving that this is poetry, maybe this is not so simple.

Comment: I take it to mean 'daughters [mentally] crushed by the hard circumstances of their lives'.

Comment: @KateBunting ty, but did the lives crush (or crush something), or did the daughters crush (or crush themselves)?

Comment: _Whom life had crushed_ means that life had crushed the daughters (as does _crushed by_ in my previous comment).

Comment: @KateBunting ty again. "Whom" could be substituted by "whose"? And for the first sentence? Would you like to post a more complete answer?

Comment: [Whom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whom) is the object form of _who_. No, it cannot be substituted by _whose_. 'Daughters whom life had crushed' means 'daughters who had been crushed by life', presumably meaning that they had had hard lives which had damaged their physical or mental health. I don't know how I can explain it any more clearly.